# Meteor npm run script on server restart

Tags: meteor, npm

Is there a way to run an npm script on every Meteor server restart?

I tried the `postinstall` hook but it runs only at the first local application start.

I assume, that there must be way, because the restart triggers several building processes and some of them must be "hookable".

I was first thinking of using [build plugins](https://docs.meteor.com/api/packagejs.html#build-plugin-api), but it seems, that they move a lot of config away from my `package.json` then.

Anyone knows something about this?

Answer (score 1):

You can run your npm script within your `Meteor.startup()` code on the server side. The following example which should be located under the `/server` folder might help.

```
import { exec } from 'child_process';

Meteor.startup(() => {
   async function sh(cmd) {
     return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
       exec(cmd, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
         if (err) {
           reject(err);
         } else {
           resolve({ stdout, stderr });
         }
       });
     });
   }

   async function excScript() {
     let { stdout } = await sh('npm -ls'); // runs "npm -ls"
     for (let line of stdout.split('\n')) {
       console.log(`npm -ls: ${line}`);
     }
   } 
   excScript();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems, that this goes in a right direction. However, there are some errors. First it can't reach the script, because in development the folder of the local build is `{projectpath}/.meteor/local/build/programs/server` which does not contain the original `package.json` file. Is there a way to call the script "some dirs above"? The second issue is the following error message: `(node:56566) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.`

Comment: Do you mean when it runs `npm -ls` you get "command not found error" ? If so, it is related with your environment setup. You should add "npm_bin_path" to your PATH variable in your production server.   
The one related with the usage of Promise is not an error but a deprecation warning, you can omit it for now.

Comment: Thank you. I am not running on windows, so no `PATH`variables. Also I just want to use the scripts in development mode. The `command not found` error comes from the current directory being not my project directory but the local build in the `.meteor` folder, where the `package.json` with my script is not present (thus the error). Regarding depracation warning, I would not like to omit deprecated functions, since there is a reason why they are deprecated (it may not be good to deploy a new application with already deprecated features). Are there any other options to solve this? Best, Jan